# Why are some python variables uppercase whereas others are lowercase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pep8

I often see uppercase and lowercase single character variables. I’m not sure if the case is chosen because the variable is an instance of a class, float32, or just personal preference.

Here is an example from Tensorflow's getting started guide.
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

```
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
```

I'm trying to understand if there is a specific reason why W is capitalized whereas b is lowercase when both are of the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not a reflection of Python per se but of the math it captures. Usually the coefficients on x is a matrix which has a convention of being an uppercase variable. That this is a 1-dimensional example you're seeing obscures this convention, higher dimensions would be more telling.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference for Python. People usually follow the same nomenclature used in the literature, for example, E for energy is usually capitalized, or names for matrices. It is just a personal choice.

Comment: If you're writing your code to be read by Python people (as opposed to math people), they'll expect PEP-8 compliance. On the other hand, if the audience here is math people, hewing to their convention makes sense. In neither case is this "personal choice", exactly, except inasmuch as it's a judgment call as to which audience to select and thus whose conventions to follow.

Comment: And physicists have different conventions, so do engineers. At the end, the names you assign to your variables is completely a personal choice, unless you are requited to use some convention by a superior or something.

Comment: I don't agree that picking the conventions appropriate to the field you're in (or for the people you expect to read your code) is "personal choice". You're **following a convention**, not making something up willy-nilly. And if you *are* making something up willy-nilly without view to any convention whatsoever, that's likely to be frowned on (I'd certainly frown on if it if I were reviewing a potential hire's code on GitHub and they couldn't describe a rationale behind their choices).